# Python - How to plot 3D surface from scatter plot (with log scale)?

Tags: python

[image]

I want to plot Volume_norm as my x-axis, dMidP as y and Time as z.
[image]
That's the 2D plot of volume against dMidP, both shown in log scale.

Now I want to plot a 3D surface plot using these data, with dMidP and Volume_norm in log scale

(`ax.set_xscale('log')
ax.set_yscale('log')`) is not working

Here is an example of my dataframe:

```
df = {'Time' : ['2016-10-03 11:00:22','2016-10-03 11:00:27','2016-10-03 11:00:58','2016-10-03 11:01:39','2016-10-03 11:01:58','2016-10-03 11:02:23'], 'dMidP' : [0.000288, 0.000115, 0.000115, 0.000115, 0.000115, 0.000115], 'Volume_norm' : [0.464, 0.464, 0.927, 0.056, 0.464, 0.928]}
```

so far, I've plot the 3D scatter plot, but I'm struggle to build a surface plot on top of this, and I cannot convert x and y axis to log scale

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
FormatStrFormatter
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
x = df['Volume_norm']
y = df['dMidP']
z = df['Time']
ax.set_xlabel('Volume')
ax.set_ylabel('dMidP')
ax.set_zlabel('Time')

ax.scatter(x,y,z)
plt.show()
```

the code that is not working:

```
surf = ax.plot_surface(df['Volume_norm'],df['dMidP'],df['Time'])
ax.loglog(x,y)
ax.set_xscale('log')
ax.set_yscale('log')
```

Comment: Not working how? Show your code and explain how the actual result differs from your desired output.

Comment: Are you using matplotlib with Python 3? Showing the code, would make it easier to provide a relevant answer. Before I got a 3d scatter plot working starting from the documentation at https://matplotlib.org/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/tutorial.html.

Comment: Question edited. Please let me know if further clarification needed

Comment: ive checked the website but it still cant solve my problem. do you mind take a look?